# Spacy not tokenizing periods

Tags: spacy

How do I fix/adjust for the fact that spacy does not separate the period that ends a sentence if the final "word" is a non-word that includes a period?

```
>>> nlp = spacy.spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
>>> doc = nlp("The Eiffel Tower is located at 48.86N 2.29E.")
>>> print(doc[-1])
2.29E.
>>> print(nlp("The Eiffel Tower is very beautiful.")[-1])
.
```

I'm trying to extract (named-entity-recognize) the lat/lon references in the document and cannot figure out a way to make it so that extracted entity corresponds to the text `"48.86N 2.29E"` without the final period.

I want to keep all of the other usual (English) tokenizing rules un-modified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a custom suffix in your tokenizer. This can be done as follows:

```py
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

suffix_re = re.compile(r'''\.$''')

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, suffix_search=suffix_re.search)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)

doc = nlp("The Eiffel Tower is very beautiful.")
print([t.text for t in doc])

doc2 = nlp("The Eiffel Tower is located at 48.86N 2.29E.")
print([t.text for t in doc2])

doc3 = nlp("The Eiffel Tower, Norte Dame and Champs Elysee are located at 48.86N 2.29E.")
print([t.text for t in doc3])
```

**Output**

```
['The', 'Eiffel', 'Tower', 'is', 'very', 'beautiful', '.']
['The', 'Eiffel', 'Tower', 'is', 'located', 'at', '48.86N', '2.29E', '.']
['The', 'Eiffel', 'Tower,', 'Norte', 'Dame', 'and', 'Champs', 'Elysee', 'are', 'located', 'at', '48.86N', '2.29E', '.']
```

Comment: I want to keep all of the other tokenization rules in place, e.g. this will not separate off ',' from words followed by commas in a regular sentence.

Comment: @Dave: This only applies for periods. It should not separate off ',' from words followed by commas in a regular sentence. See edit above.